# Is there a way specify an email other than the user to single sign on to Dropbox using AAD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, dropbox

I'm setting up single sign-on for Dropbox with the Azure Active Directory - in a web app I'm currently working on. Everything is working fine, but, there are a group of users that share the same Dropbox account.

How can I make the single sign-on in Dropbox to use an email different that the logged user?